# Devise: what value is saved in the cookie when remember me is checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

I have the following question, as from title: what value is saved in the cookie when remember me is checked?

In the book I read there was an attribute in the User table (remember_token) where I saved (crypted) the remember_token value saved in the cookie.

Here with devise I do not see an attribute called remember_token, so what is saved? the email crypted?

Anothere question what means the following code in the `devise.rb`

```
# Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]
```

I do not understand, why does it need a key to be declared? What does it do?